# How can I use MsSqlConnectionParameters to get connection parameters of a xtrareport in Wpf?

Tags: wpf, devexpress, xtrareport

I have .repx file (Xtrareport - Devexpress) . I want to get connection parameters of this file and change them. How can I do it? In .repx file, the parameters are below :

```
        msSqlConnectionParameters1.AuthorizationType =           
        DevExpress.DataAccess.ConnectionParameters.MsSqlAuthorizationType.Windows;
        msSqlConnectionParameters1.DatabaseName = "report";
        msSqlConnectionParameters1.Password = "";
        msSqlConnectionParameters1.ServerName = "localhost";
        msSqlConnectionParameters1.UserName = "";
```

I want to access these parameters in wpf project....

Comment: Isn't there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument2592):

> It's possible to store its (report) *definition* (layout and configuration). <...>
>   Report definitions are saved to files in REPX format.

It means that `.repx` file does not contain any connection parameters. After loading the report from `.repx` file you need to set its data source:

```
var report = new XtraReport();
report.LoadLayout(filePath);
report.DataSource = someDataSource;
```

So, the answer to your question is:
It is not possible to use `MsSqlConnectionParameters` to get connection parameters of a `XtraReport` which is saved in `.repx` file in `Wpf` or in somewhere else.